# Do we have $x^TDAx\ge \min(\lambda_D)\min(\lambda_A)x^Tx$ if $A$ is PD and D is both diagonal and PD?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Suppose matrix $A\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ is symmetric positive definite and $D\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ is both diagonal and positive definite, do we have the following result?
$$x^TDAx\ge \min(\lambda_D)\min(\lambda_A)x^Tx,\quad \forall x\in\mathbb{R}^n$$
where $ \min(\lambda_D)$ and $\min(\lambda_A)$ are the minimum eigenvalues of $D$ and $A$, respectively.

I know $DA$ is not symmetric any more, and I feel the above result is wrong. But I cannot find a counterexample. What's your opinion? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, the inequality does not always hold. Here is a counterexample:
$$
D=\pmatrix{1&0\\ 0&3},\ A=\pmatrix{1&2\\ 2&5},\ DA=\pmatrix{1&2\\ 6&15},\ x=(4,-1)^T,\ x^TDAx=-1,
$$
but $\min(\lambda_D)\min(\lambda_A)x^Tx$ is positive because both $D$ and $A$ are positive definite and $x$ is nonzero.

Comment: Thank you. Do you think it is possible to identify the condition under which that result in my OP is valid? Is it possible to identify the condition by analyzing the eigenvalues of $DA$?

Comment: @Shiyu Nothing immediately comes to mind, but merely analysing the eigenvalues of $DA$ is futile. What important here are the eigenvalues of the *symmetric part* of $DA$, not the eigenvalues of $DA$. In fact, the eigenvalues of $DA$ are always positive because $DA$ is similar to $D^{1/2}AD^{1/2}$, which is positive definite. So, given the spectrum of $DA$, you can always construct $D'$ and $A'$ such that $D'A'$ is symmetric positive definite and possesses the same spectrum as $DA$ (just take $A'=I$ and $D'$ as the eigenvalue matrix).

Comment: Thanks a lot. very helpful comments. Did you write "By the way, strict diagonal dominance of xxx". I received in my inbox but can't see it on this page.

Comment: @Shiyu One rather useless suff. cond. is that $DA+AD$ is strictly diag. dominant, i.e. $2d_ia_{ii} > \sum_{j\neq i} (d_i+d_j)|a_{ij}|$ for all $i$. This happens when $\frac{d_\max}{d_\min} < \min_ia_{ii}\left/\sum_{j\neq i} |a_{ij}|\right.$. While this condition is too strong, I think that for your ineq. to hold, the nec./suff. cond. are more or less of this sort. That is, the ratios $d_i/d_j$ cannot be too large. This is somewhat necessary: if some such ratio is too large, the $2\times 2$ submatrix of $DA+AD$ will be indefinite.

Comment: And this is somewhat sufficient: when $D$ is close to a scalar multiple of $I$, by continuity of eigenvalues, $DA+AD$ would be positive definite. Certainly, the feasible ratios in the nec. part and the suff. part may not match, but the idea is that the orders of magnitude of the diagonal entries of $D$ cannot vary too much.

Comment: Oops, sorry, these are not conditions for your ineq. to hold, but only conditions for $DA+AD$ to be +ve definite.

Comment: I agree. The condition for the inequality should be somehow that the diagonal matrix is sufficiently close to a scalar multiple of $I$. In your last comment, what is +ve definite?

Comment: @Shiyu Positive definite.

Comment: Oh, didn't know that:)

Answer (score 0):

Let $A=\left[\array{5 &3\\3 & 2}\right]$, $x=\left[\array{1 \\-1 }\right]$, and $D=\left[\array{1 &0\\0 & 2}\right]$. We have $Ax =\left[\array{2\\1}\right]$ and $x^TD=\left[\array{1 &-2}\right]$ so $x^TDAx=0$.